# For every file modification copy it into another file bash

Tags: linux, bash, inotifywait

I want to run service to listen on file modifying and for every add to file delete it from file and append to another file 
I tried this code but it is not working it like going in infinite loop

```
   inotifywait -m -e modify "$1" |
    while read folder eventlist eventfile
    do
        cat "$1">>$DESTINATION_FILE
        >$1
    done
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: get the modify on many files

Comment: So basically, you want to append the diff to `$DESTINATION_FILE` for every modification?

Answer (score 2):

Each time you truncate the file, that registers as a modification, which triggers another truncation, etc. Try testing if the file contains anything in the body of the loop.

```
inotifywait -m -e modify "$1" |
while read folder eventlist eventfile
do
    # Only copy-and-clear if the file is not empty
    if [ -s "$1" ]; then
        cat "$1" >> "$DESTINATION_FILE"
        # What if the file is modified here?
        >$1
    fi
done
```

See my comment between `cat` and the truncation. You would never put those modifications in `$DESTINATION_FILE`, because you would erase them before the next iteration of the loop. This isn't really avoidable, unless your operating system allows you to obtain a lock on `$1` prior to the `cat`, then release the lock after the truncation, so that only one process can write to the file at a time.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by chepner, the reverting of the changes will also be treated as file modify.

A way out is:

1. remove -m parameter
2. Manually implement a while loop in bash

e.g.

```
cp "$1" "$1.bak"
while true; do inotifywait -e modify "$1" | {
    read folder eventlist eventfile;
    cat "$1" >> "$DESTINATION_FILE";
    # OR
    # diff  "$1" "$1.bak"  >> "$DESTINATION_FILE";
    cp "$1.bak" "$1";
    }
done
```

Note: I haven't tested above code myself.

Note2: There may be atomicity issues. There are times when the file modifications are not being monitored. Hence, when this `cat >` operation or `cp` operations are in progress, someone may attempt to write to `"$1"` file, which will be missed.